# how to determine size of tablespace oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g, tablespace

I have a database with three tables. I need to move historic partitioned data to other schema
Now that i´m planning to creatre the new "historic" tables. I don´t know how to measure the size of partition and subpartitions. Can u help me? please gimme some advices.

Thanxs in advance.
Lou

Comment: You talk about tablespaces in your title but partitions and subpartitions in the text. Which one is it? And what have you tried? There's a lot of stuff available with a simple search, why didn't the basic stuff meet your needs?

Comment: @user2115594:dude you need to measure the tablespace size or each partition size in a particular table?

Comment: Yeah i´m sorry what i really need is to measure the subpartition size in my origin table. Each origin tables where created with partitions and subpartitions but they all insert data into 3 tablespaces. Next step is to create one tablespace for each subpartition

Answer (score 47):

The following query can be used to detemine tablespace and other params:

```
select df.tablespace_name "Tablespace",
       totalusedspace "Used MB",
       (df.totalspace - tu.totalusedspace) "Free MB",
       df.totalspace "Total MB",
       round(100 * ( (df.totalspace - tu.totalusedspace)/ df.totalspace)) "Pct. Free"
  from (select tablespace_name,
               round(sum(bytes) / 1048576) TotalSpace
          from dba_data_files 
         group by tablespace_name) df,
       (select round(sum(bytes)/(1024*1024)) totalusedspace,
               tablespace_name
          from dba_segments 
         group by tablespace_name) tu
 where df.tablespace_name = tu.tablespace_name 
   and df.totalspace <> 0;
```

Source: https://community.oracle.com/message/1832920

For your case if you want to know the partition name and it's size just run this query:

```
select owner,
       segment_name,
       partition_name,
       segment_type,
       bytes / 1024/1024 "MB" 
  from dba_segments 
 where owner = <owner_name>;
```

Comment: Is it posible to know the size of subpartitions in MB or Gigas?

Comment: Is there any query like this to measure temp tablespaces?

Answer (score 18):

One of the way is
Using below sql queries

```
--Size of All Table Space

--1. Used Space
SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME,TO_CHAR(SUM(NVL(BYTES,0))/1024/1024/1024, '99,999,990.99') AS "USED SPACE(IN GB)" FROM USER_SEGMENTS GROUP BY TABLESPACE_NAME
--2. Free Space
SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME,TO_CHAR(SUM(NVL(BYTES,0))/1024/1024/1024, '99,999,990.99') AS "FREE SPACE(IN GB)" FROM   USER_FREE_SPACE GROUP BY TABLESPACE_NAME

--3. Both Free & Used
SELECT USED.TABLESPACE_NAME, USED.USED_BYTES AS "USED SPACE(IN GB)",  FREE.FREE_BYTES AS "FREE SPACE(IN GB)"
FROM
(SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME,TO_CHAR(SUM(NVL(BYTES,0))/1024/1024/1024, '99,999,990.99') AS USED_BYTES FROM USER_SEGMENTS GROUP BY TABLESPACE_NAME) USED
INNER JOIN
(SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME,TO_CHAR(SUM(NVL(BYTES,0))/1024/1024/1024, '99,999,990.99') AS FREE_BYTES FROM  USER_FREE_SPACE GROUP BY TABLESPACE_NAME) FREE
ON (USED.TABLESPACE_NAME = FREE.TABLESPACE_NAME);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to [check the tablespace size](https://www.oraask.com/2021/04/check-tablespace-usage-in-oracle.html) in oracle is to run this query

```
SELECT   TABLESPACE_NAME, ROUND (SUM (BYTES) / 1048576) "Total Size MB"
    FROM     DBA_DATA_FILES
    GROUP BY TABLESPACE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT b.tablespace_name, tbs_size SizeGb, a.free_space FreeGb
FROM (  SELECT tablespace_name,
ROUND (SUM (bytes) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 2) AS free_space
FROM dba_free_space
GROUP BY tablespace_name) a,
(  SELECT tablespace_name, SUM (bytes) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 AS tbs_size
FROM dba_data_files
GROUP BY tablespace_name) b
WHERE a.tablespace_name(+) = b.tablespace_name
ORDER BY 1